# Script sudo via ssh

Tags: linux, bash, amazon-ec2, ssh, sudo

I am trying to create a shell script that allows me to automatically remote into my AWS EC2 instance from my local machine. I also want this script to log me in as 'root' user and to a directory named '/var/files'. Currently, the script allows me to connect into my EC2 instance but not as 'root' user or into the directory I want.

My question is, how do I pass the "sudo su" and "cd /var/files" to the command line after remoting in? Here is what I have so far but it doesn't pass the $USER and $PATH variables to the command-line.

```
cd "C:\Operations\sys_admin"
ssh -i "mykeypair.pem" ec2-user@[IP].[location].compute.amazonaws.com 
USER='sudo su'
PATH='cd /var/files'
echo $USER
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about writing these command into the `~/.bashrc` of the ec2-user? You would need to add `sudo su` and `cd /var/files` as two lines. That would of course mean, that **every** time you log onto the server you would change to root and cd into the directory...

Otherwise you could use `ssh -t` in the following way:

`ssh -i "mykeypair.pem" -t ec2-user@[IP].[location].compute.amazonaws.com 'sudo su -c "cd /var/files; bash -l"'`

Basically as @blake-percy pointed out but with the `-l` option

Comment: that is certainly one option but, I would prefer not to modify the permissions for the ec2-user so that every time I login I am in a that directory.

Comment: okay great, well I am in as root now used the about command. The only problem is that it does not bring me to the /var/files/ direction so it seams the "cd /var/files/" command is not being passed. Any idea how this should be modified? thanks!

Comment: I changed the answer. Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

```
cd "C:\Operations\sys_admin"
ssh -i "mykeypair.pem" ec2-user@[IP].[location].compute.amazonaws.com 
sudo su
cd /var/files
```

Comment: I tried that, but it just hangs on "[ec2-user@[location] ~]$".

Answer (score -1):

```
ssh -t -i "mykeypair.pem" ec2-user@[IP].[location].compute.amazonaws.com "sudo su; cd /var/files; bash"
```